# PHP unwanted autosubmit

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, post

I have this list of DB entries in HTML and I wanted a edit button next to each row to be able to update the users info. The POST variables get to the .php file that updates the database row, the problem is that I can only edit the last row of the list, it seems like it submits the data via POST automatically. I would like to submit the data only after the Edit button has been pressed.

**Show current member info and on-click redirect to a .php file where the query itself is executed**

```css
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("users") or die(mysql_error());

$id = $_POST['id'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE id LIKE $id";

$result = mysql_query($query);

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title></title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css">
 <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="well">
            <form action="edit.php" class="form-horizontal well" method="post">
                <fieldset>
                  <legend>Edit a member</legend>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-8">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="rows">
                                        <div class="col-md-8">
                                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                                <input class="form-control input-lg" id="name" name="name" value="<?php echo $row['name'] ?>" type="text">
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                                <input class="form-control input-lg" id="surname" name="surname" value="<?php echo $row['surname'] ?>" type="text">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="rows">
                                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                                    <input class="form-control input-lg" id="address" name="address" value="<?php echo $row['address'] ?>" type="text">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="rows">
                                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                                    <input class="form-control input-lg" id="number" name="number" value="<?php echo $row['number'] ?>" type="text">
                                                    <input type='hidden' name='id' value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="rows">
                                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                                        <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg" type="submit">Update member details</button>
                                                        <div class="btn btn-info"><a href="index.php">View member DB</a></div>        

                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
 
                            </div>
 
   </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
 </div>
    </div><!-- /container -->

</body>

</html>
```

**Listing of current users (db rows)**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("users") or die(mysql_error());
?>

<html>
<head>

 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title></title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css">
 <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="well">
                    <h2 class="text-center">List of members</h2>
                    <hr width="75%">
                    <table class="table table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <th width="6%" align="left">Member ID</th>
                            <th width="7%" align="left">First Name</th>
                            <th width="7%" align="left">Last Name</th>
                            <th width="7%" align="center">Address</th>
                            <th width="7%" align="center">Number</th>
                            <th width="7%" align="center">Edit</th>
                        </thead>
                        
                        <tbody>
                            <?php
                                $query = 'SELECT * FROM userinfo';
                                $result = mysql_query($query);
                                
                                
                                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                                   
                                    echo ' <tr> ';
                                    echo ' <td> ';
                                    echo $row['id'];
                                    echo ' <td> ';
                                    echo $row['name'];
                                    echo ' <td> ';
                                    echo $row['surname'];
                                    echo ' <td> ';
                                    echo $row['address'];
                                    echo ' <td> ';
                                    echo $row['number'];
                                    echo "<td><form action='info.php' method='POST'><input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$row['id']."'/><input type='submit' name='submit-btn' value='View/Update Details' /><form></td></tr>";
                                }
                            ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="btn btn-info"><a href="insertform.html">Insert a new member</a></div>        
        <div class="btn btn-danger"><a href="clear.php">Clear table</a></div>

        
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
<form>
```

with

```
</form>
```

to end the form properly, otherwise it will be seen as only one form and the values of the last row will be used, since they are duplicated (one form contains all fields)

Answer (score 0):

replace your edit buttom code.

```
echo "<td><form action='info.php' method='POST'><input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$row['id']."'/><input type='submit' name='submit-btn' value='View/Update Details' /><form></td></tr>";
```

with this code

```
echo '<a href="update.php/'. $row["id"].'"';
```